# iOS Dismiss Alert Open Textfield

Tags: ios, uialertview

Is there a way in iOS to open up the textfield (Like the user clicked on it (bringing up the keyboard)) after they dismiss an alert?
Don't have any code to show because I have no idea where to start! :)

Comment: textfield inside alert?

Comment: No, not "in Xcode". There may be something in the **Cocoa (Touch) API,** though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UIAlertViewDelegate`  method.

On `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method ,put the code to show the textfield, by changing `hidden` property or `addSubview:`

and to bring up the keyboard

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks I just added ([textField becomeFirstResponder];) to my action button in my alert so when they click okay it brings it up! Thanks!